# Bounded second moments implies convergence! Clarify please

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Really simple question here:

$$\textit{Does uniformly bounded second moments imply convergence?} $$

Let $P(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $\{\mu_n\}_{n}\subset P(\mathbb{R}^d)$, with second moments denoted as $M(\mu_n)$. Assume that for some constant $C>0$ the second moments are uniformly bounded$$\sup_{n}M(\mu_n)=\sup_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|x|^2d\mu_n(x)\leq C.$$

$\textbf{Claim :}$

1. There exists a $\mu \in P(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $M(\mu)\leq C$ and $\mu_n \overset{weakly}{\longrightarrow} \mu$ (up to a subsequence).
2. Moreover, $W_2(\mu_n,\mu)\to 0$ (up to a subsequence), where $W_2$ is the Wasserstein metric.

Could anyone clarify if the above claim is correct (I provide a proof below, I am not sure it is correct).

---

$\textbf{Proof :}$
Let the random variable $X_n\sim \mu_n$.

i) The uniformly bounded second moments imply the sequence $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight. Hence by Prokhorov theorem, it weakly converges (atleast along a subsequence) to some limit $\mu$, moreover $M(\mu) \leq C$ (by Fatous Lemma).

2. The uniformly bounded second moments imply the sequence $\{\mu_n\}$ has uniformly inetegrable 2-moments i.e.

$$ \lim_{r\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d\backslash B_r(0)} \|x\|^2 d\mu_n(x) =0. $$  This is ensured by Markov inequality

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_n| 1_{\{|X_n|>r}) \leq \frac{1}{r} \mathbb{E}(|X_n|^2 1_{|X_n|>r}) \leq \frac{1}{r} \mathbb{E}(|X_n|^2) \leq C \frac{1}{r} \to_{r\to \infty} 0. $$

Now take the weakly converging subsequence. Weak convergence in combination with uniformly integrable 2-moments implies convergence in $W_2$ (see Gradient flows in metric spaces and in the
space of probability measures (by Ambrosio, Gigli, Savare) Proposition 7.1.5).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community if my claim/proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the first part.

For the second part, you proved only uniform integrability of the first moments of $\mu_n$; that of the second may not hold, and the result as well. For example, for $d=1$, let $\mu_n=\frac 1n\delta_{\sqrt n}+\left(1-1/n\right)\delta_0$. This converges in distribution to $\delta_0$ but the Wasserstein distance $W_2(\mu_n,\delta_0)$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: So theres no way I can use the uniform bounded 2nd moments to get the $W_2$ convergence?

Comment: You need uniform integrability of the second moments; a uniform bound is not enough

Comment: Ok I noticed my mistake, thanks